# facebook not redirecting within inappbrowser

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, inappbrowser

Having an issue when I make a Facebook call from `InAppBrowser`.
The Facebook call works but it will not redirect back.

It gets stuck on this URL

***www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close?#_=_***

The `InAppBrowser` loads up my `WordPress` website so all the Facebook calls are from plugins I've installed on my WordPress site.

I tried to redirect it using this code

```
if (event.url.match("www.facebook.com/dialog/return/close?#_=_")) {
       //Redirect code here!
    }
```

but had no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inappbrowser not redirecting after facebook call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589975/inappbrowser-not-redirecting-after-facebook-call)